# EditText stretches my text

Tags: android, android-layout

this is how my Edit text looks. it stretches my text and adds unwanted space between words

[image]

this is the text in strings.xml:

```
<string name="type_msg">Type your message...</string>
```

and this is the layout xml code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"                   
            android:background="@drawable/chat_text_box_corners"
            android:maxLines="4"     
            android:minLines="1"   
            android:scrollbars="vertical"                                   
            android:hint="@string/type_msg"               
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
            android:paddingRight="10dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_message"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/call_btn"               
           />
```

it acts the same when i type:

[image]

Comment: when u edit the edittext how it is, may be hint text format like this

Comment: does it take spaces even when you enter some text?

Comment: i just tried , its all correct for me , check something  if you put OnTextChnage listener

Comment: nice try. i removed the OnTextChnage listener and it still happens

Answer (score 0):

There is `settext` attribute in android used for horizontal scaling `oftext`..accordingly adjust your text.

Check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textScaleX